# uploading file and store to the filesystem in php

Tags: php, pdf, upload, doc

i want to upload pdf or doc files in php, and i dont want to store it in the databse rather in filesystem. but am geting an error when i try to do that.....
here is my code

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

 $allowedExts = array("pdf", "doc","docx");
 $extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "'application/pdf")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == " application/x-pdf")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/acrobat")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "applications/vnd.pdf")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "text/pdf")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "text/x-pdf"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
{
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{
echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
}
else
{
echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
  {
  echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
  }
else
  {
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
  "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
  echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
  }
  }
}
 else
{
echo "Invalid file";
 }

}
?>
```

i dont know if the file is uploaded where but it returns error when file is not pdf or doc...any help please?

**when i edit to this it works fine**

```
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: i don get an error...i think files are uploaded, but i dont knw where to find them

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the upload folder permission to 775 ?

Also, Try:

```
$allowedExts = array("pdf", "docx");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/pdf")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/msword")
```

Play around with that using [MIME Types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type).

Comment: am on localhost, so do i need to create this upload folder? n where do i create it??

Comment: according to your script, you are trying to upload the files into a folder called `upload`, so in the same dir as this script, create a folder called `upload`.

Comment: i did wat u said,but nothing is uploaded in the folder

Comment: when i change allowed format to images it works, so can i do this in restricting pdf and docx?? see my update please

Comment: it still fails,i get this error   "Invalid file" when i try to upload pdf

Comment: try editing the allowedexts array aswell as the accepted mime types

Answer (score 0):

It returns an error when you upload a doc or a pdf, because that is the only extensions you allow your file to have. You do this in 
$allowedExts = array("pdf", "doc","docx");